# Unexpected behavior with strnatcmp() PHP

Tags: php, auto-increment, behavior

I'm trying to get a function to increment alphas upwards in PHP from say A->ZZ or AAA -> ZZZ with all the variations in between, ie. A, B, C...AA, AB, AC..ZX, ZY, ZZ etc..

The following code works sometimes, but then breaks in certain instances, this example works perfectly.

```
$from = "A";
$to = "ZZ";

while(strnatcmp($from, $to) <= 0) {           
    echo $from++;
}
```

While this does not work as expected.

```
$from = "A";
$to = "BB";

while(strnatcmp($from, $to) <= 0) {
    echo $from++;
}
```

Output is:

```
First: A B C D .. AA AB AC .. ZX ZY ZZ
Second: A B
```

Does any one know what's going on here? or maybe a different approach to my problem.
Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Like the first example all the variations in-between. A, B, C...AA, AB, AC...BA, BB

Comment: I guess it's saying that B == BB but that doesn't make sense does it?

Comment: Nice examples. I've just tried the same thing with a standard `while ($from !== $to) echo $from++;` and seeing the same results. *Note:* strict comparison doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @NexxTea it's stopping on `C` ... `strnatcmp('C', 'BB') = 1` because `C` is greater than `BB`.

Comment: oh yes, of course, I think I need to restructure my approach, thanks guys.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Ah ok, can't use generators then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but it stops on `BA` ... so you can either say `$to = 'BC';` or you can toss in a `$to++;` right after you declare `$to`.

```
$from= 'A';
$to = 'BB';
while ($from !== $to) {
    echo $from++;
}

$from= 'A';
$to = 'BB';
$to++;
while ($from !== $to) {
    echo $from++;
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use a generator.

```
function alphaRange($from, $to) {
    ++$to;
    for ($i = $from; $i !== $to; ++$i) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

foreach (alphaRange('A', 'BB') as $char) {
    echo $char;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $from = "AA";
    $to = "BB";

    while(strnatcmp($from, $to) <= 0)           
        echo $from++ . "<br />";

?>
```

The Output is:

```
AA...BB
```

If you want the Alphabet first too, then copy this before the code from above:

```
$from = "A";
$to = "Z";

while(strnatcmp($from, $to) <= 0)           
    echo $from++ . "<br />";
```

Comment: the input from the user will be any thing between A and ZZZZZ, I need to be able to generate all combinations in between two inputs. Like lets say AZT and ZPTSR for example